# I need to carmalize the first letter of each word in an array

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict";
function carmalize(newArr)
{

     for(var i = 1 ; i < newArr.length ; i++){
        newArr[i] = newArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    }       
    return newArr[i].join(" ");
}
console.log(carmalize(["brett","john","peter"]));
```

I need to carmalize the first letter of each word in an array

Comment: carmalize? do you mean to make it uppercase? Or are you talking about the camelCase notation?

Comment: Do you mean camelCase?

Comment: \*dumps code\* -> "I need it to do this". Uh, ok? You might want to explain what "carmalize" is first; then you might want to explain what your code does or doesn't do (any errors?) and tell us what *exactly* you need help with.

Comment: I think you mean capitalize?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start from the first character which has index `0` not `1`:

```
for(var i = 0
```

You need to uppercase the first letter then append the remainder of the string back to the array:

```
newArr[i] = newArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newArr[i].substr(1);
```

`Join` the whole array, not a specific index of the array:

```
return newArr.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from running your `i` loop from 0, you need

`newArr[i] = newArr[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + newArr[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();`

to convert each element. Currently you're extracting just the first character from each element, and converting that to upper case; all subsequent characters are discarded.

Marking your parameter `newArr` is misleading given that you modify the elements *in-place*.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code:

```
function carmalize(newArr) {

 for(var i = 0 ; i < newArr.length ; i++){
    newArr[i] = newArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newArr[i].substring(1);
 }       
 return newArr;
}
console.log(carmalize(["brett","john","peter"]));
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: thank you so much this worked very well I am very appreciative.

Answer (score -1):

> Object Oriented Approach

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

You can create a function in string.

```
"use strict";
function carmalize(newArr)
{
     var newArray = [];
     for ( var i = 0 ; i < newArr.length ; i++ ) {
        newArray.push(newArr[i].capitalize());
    }       
    return newArray.join();
}
console.log( carmalize(["brett","john","peter"]));
```